# How to view layout-sequence diagram (activity-sequence diagram or user-interface-sequence diagram) in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sequence-diagram

I have an android application in android studio, and this app has about 10 activities (or user interfaces).

**I can't find where and how I could view the sequence diagram of the activities (or ui) of my android studio application.**

I'm looking a plugin for android-studio or something like that. At one point earlier in my usage of android-studio, I seem to recall being able to pressed a button and get to the the UI-sequence-diagram. I can't find that now.

Could anyone offer any help for viewing the sequence diagram of my user-interfaces of my app?

Comment: Are you looking for something like Storyboards in Xcode for iOS dev? There isn't a tool like that in Android Studio unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know what is Storyboards, I'm looking a plugin for android-studio or something like that. At my beginning in android-studio, I pressed a button(I don't know it now) then I get the UI-sequence-diagram.

Comment: This? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `Tools -> Android -> Navigation Editor`

Comment: It was an experimental feature that was removed in Android Studio 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no "one button" solution that interrogates your code and spits out a diagram any longer.  There was once an [experimental feature](http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor) that was later removed from Android Studio.

But starting with Android Studio 3.3, you can create your application using **Navigation Component**, which gives you the diagram you're after.

You define the **Navigation graph**, which results in an XML file that has all of your navigation specifics.  If you go through the trouble to recode your application to use `NavController` (and the related components), you not only get the diagram, but this scheme takes care of a lot of up and back actions automatically, and lets you pass data between activities with ease.